# Errror when writing ML pipeline: Cannot write a schema with an empty group: message spark_schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I have some problem with saving Spark ML Pipeline. I am using Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.3.1.

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(stages)

// It's working
pipeline.save("/tmp/example")

// It's not working
val modelPipeline = pipeline.fit(ds)
modelPipeline.save("/tmp/example")
```

I have this error. I was looking for a solution on the Internet. I found some information about this same error, but writing data to parquet. I don't know why I have this error when I am writing ML Pipeline.

```
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.schema.InvalidSchemaException: Cannot write a schema with an empty group: message spark_schema {
}

    at org.apache.parquet.schema.TypeUtil$1.visit(TypeUtil.java:27)
    at org.apache.parquet.schema.TypeUtil$1.visit(TypeUtil.java:37)
    at org.apache.parquet.schema.MessageType.accept(MessageType.java:58)
    at org.apache.parquet.schema.TypeUtil.checkValidWriteSchema(TypeUtil.java:23)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:225)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:342)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:302)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Instead of saving, can you actually use the fitted pipeline (i.e. use `transform`)?

Comment: I need to save, because I want to use it later.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But it would be interesting to see if it gives an error or not when running `transform()`.

Comment: Good idea. I will try.

Comment: I have this same error after using transform.